# Tap vs swipe event on Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing an app for WP8, and I'm having some issues...

When I slide/swipe/scroll my *LongListBox* in the emulator, the *Tap* event gets triggered!

How can I differentiate between a tap and a swipe gesture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a bug with the emulator.

You could always just check for the events when releasing, rather than relying on gestures, so that you can determine if they indeed tapped or swiped.

Alternatively, have someone test for you on Windows 8 to see if it's an actual issue with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be to do with bubbling of events. In Windows Phone this can be easily handled using the IsHitTestVisible property.